# symmetric matrix right and left singular matrix of a symmetric matrix

Tags: svd

For a symmetric matrix, the SVD is $$A = USV^T$$
and, since $A = A^T$, we have $$USV^T = VSU^T$$
$(S = S^T)$, but how to prove $U=V$?

Comment: In general, we **can't** take $U = V$; that only happens if $A$ additionally has non-negative eigenvalues.

Comment: Take $A$ to be $n\times n$ zero matrix. Then $S=A$ and *any* unitary $U,V$ give a possible SVD without $U=V$.